# First person Star Wars book about a Corellian who found out he had the Force

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, books

As the recent stories of *Star Wars* are not appealing to me, I have been going back and reading a lot of the now Legacy timeline of my childhood.   I seem to recall a book about a Corellian who found out he had the Force, and it was all written in first person.

As I'm slowly working my way through the *Thrawn Trilogy* right now, I was remembering this story and thought I would move on to it next, but I can't recall the name of the book or the author to start looking for it.

Comment: [I, Jedi](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/758654.I_Jedi#)?

Comment: @Valorum - That was my immediate thought as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [*I, Jedi*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/758654.I_Jedi#), written by Michael A. Stackpole, about a Force sensitive Corellian.

Brief synopsis from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I,_Jedi):

> In I, Jedi, Corran Horn must develop his Jedi powers in order to save the life of his wife, Mirax Terrik.
>
> Corran Horn was a member of the elite X-wing force Rogue Squadron. After returning home from a long campaign to find his wife kidnapped, he turns to Luke Skywalker, the only remaining Jedi Master at the time, for help. This coincides nicely with the master's timing, as he is seeking students for his new Jedi Academy on Yavin 4. Corran knows that he is Force-sensitive, and that only with the Force as his ally can he track down his enemy.

[image: I, Jedi front cover]

Comment: That would be it!  thanks

Comment: @jedicurt Note that Corran Horn is also a lead character in the first four and eighth books of the *X-Wing* series (also authored by Stackpole). He even finds out his Jedi heritage in one of them. At least the first 4 occur chronologically before *I, Jedi*; I'm not sure where the eighth falls in the timeline. You may want to read them for context.